# Singlestore database with one leaf

Tags: singlestore

I have one singlestore database with two Leaves. Each leaf size is 1 terabyte so it make hard to backup VM.How I can remove one leaf without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have high availability enabled in SingleStore ? You will maybe need to disable it before.

Otherwise I found out this documentation pretty straight forward from my experience have you tried described steps : [Downsizing a Cluster](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.3/en/user-and-cluster-administration/resize-your-cluster/cluster-downsizing-steps.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove one leaf without data loss, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that you have High Availability (HA) enabled on your leaf nodes to make sure that the data is properly replicated. You can enable HA using the sdb-admin enable-high-availability command.
2. If you have ensured that the leaf has a healthy pair (replicated data across both leaves), you can use the REMOVE LEAF command to safely remove the leaf without losing data. The system will rebalance the partitions onto the remaining leaves if the removed leaf doesn't have a pair. Remember that using the FORCE flag while removing the leaf will disable the automatic rebalancing, which could lead to data loss:

```sql
REMOVE LEAF 'leaf_host:leaf_port';
```

Replace leaf_host with the hostname/IP of the leaf you want to remove, and leaf_port with the port (e.g. 3306).

3. After the leaf has been removed, the partitions should be in the pair leaf. You can verify the cluster status using SHOW CLUSTER STATUS command to ensure everything is working as expected.

Make sure to run these steps in the master aggregator or a child aggregator, as the REMOVE LEAF command needs to be executed there.

Comment: After remove leaf I got :  You must add at least one leaf to the system to run CREATE DATABASE